# Toggling Active States

Tags: javascript, html, css

Easy question for a lot of you but I'm still learning. I'm trying to get better at toggling between active and inactive states of simple objects.

I have a square div:

```
<div id = "square"></div>
```

With the following css to, onclick, make the div extend

```
#square
 {
 height: 50px;
 width: 60px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 transition: height 2s ease;
}

#square:active
{
 height: 100px;
}
```

And the following javascript to set up the click event:

```
var square = document.getElementById("square").addEventListener("click",    function()
{
this.classList.toggle("active");

}, false);
```

But nothing seems to happen when I click.  I'm including JS in this because I'm also new to learning JS as well, and I'm trying to get used to simple logic principles.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/theodore_steiner/fsk6y50k/4/

Any help would be wonderful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that you used the [`class selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) is wrong,

```
#square.active{
 height: 100px;
}
```

It should precede with a `dot` not a `colon`

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fsk6y50k/6/)

Comment: One more question, why is the active state a always a (.) and attributes like #square:hover (etceteras) a colon?  And what is the difference?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Those are all [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) And they are different from normal classes.